# La variable utiliza un tipo de Automatización no admitido en Visual Basic

Tags: vba

Cuando intento acceder a las rutinas de control de eventos en la ventana de código de una hoja, desplegando el cuadro combinado y seleccionando `Worksheet`, me sale el error:

> "La variable utiliza un tipo de Automatización no admitido en Visual
> Basic"

Ocurre lo mismo si selecciono la opción de menú Depuración->Compilar VBA

¿a qué se debe esto y cómo se puede solucionar?

Estoy trabajando en Excel versión 16 para Mac

Comment: Hola! Bienvenido a SOes. ¡[Bienvenido](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/topic/error-del-editor-de-visual-basic-en-excel-para-mac-la-variable-usa-un-tipo-de-automatizaci%C3%B3n-no-admitido-c3125bf3-c30b-4d62-be42-d2f1bec0e5ad) a Office para Mac! :P

Answer (score 0):

Gracias Alfabravo por tu comentario con el enlace a la página de soporte de Microsoft.

Utilicé la opción de copiar los encabezados de las funciones que gestionan los eventos, y copié el código de una versión de Windows en las rutinas correspondientes, porque Excel para Mac, al abrir el archivo xlsm, modificado en Windows, detectaba errores y eliminaba toda el contenido VBA. Aparentemente, funciona.

Al parecer el editor de Visual Basic de MAC tiene problemas para generar los encabezados de la funciones de gestión de los eventos.

Cuando se escribe el encabezado correcto de una función de gestión de eventos, por ejemplo

```
Public Sub Worksheet_Change (ByVal Target as Range)

End Sub
```

el desplegable de los eventos se rellena adecuadamente, pero, a veces, al seleccionar uno para que genere el encabezado de la función, falla y da error, por lo que es preferible copiar los encabezados de todas las funciones de evento, aunque no tengan código.